# prevent printing control-character in insert mode and command line

Tags: command-line, insert-mode, control-character

When in insert mode, if no mapping is associated to a sequence, Vim will print the character corresponding to the signal.
For example, typing `<c-b>` will input `^b` as a character.

It is more annoying in command mode. For exemple, when I type `filetype de<c-i>`, the completion will not work and I will have `filetype de^I`.

I found out there is an option to prevent this in `bash` readline:

```
   echo-control-characters (On)
      When set to On, on operating systems that indicate  they  support  it,
      readline  echoes  a character corresponding to a signal generated from
      the keyboard.
```

Is there such a setting in Vim?

Edit: added the command mode part (which I just remembered was what always really bothered me in the first place).

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it ?

Comment: Out of pure laziness, not to have to delete them when I mistype, of course! And since it exists in bash, I was wondering if it was implemented in Vim too.

Answer (score 2):

Very few control characters are actually passed through in insert mode.  You can easily remap them to `<nop>` (do nothing) or anything more useful;

```
inoremap <c-b> <nop>
inoremap <c-f> <nop>
inoremap <c-l> <nop>
inoremap <c-z> <nop>
```

Comment: That's a workaround indeed.

Comment: I just remembered why this question was so important to me...I edited it.